# depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.10.0-19-generic

Tags: upgrade, 17.10, 17.04, dkms

I have upgraded my **Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10** and since I have done it, I  **cannot install any program anymore**.

If I try to install sth, I have the following error.

```
~$ sudo apt-get install ...

Removing linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic (4.10.0-19.21) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.10.0-19-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-19-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-19-generic
```

It seems that before installing anything, the installer tries to remove an unexisitng image of my system in my /boot folder.

Can anyone help me solving this?

Additional potential useful information according to related questions  already consulted [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916913/stuck-removing-linux-image-extra-4-10-0-19-generic).

/boot

```
 ~$ ls -la /boot

    total 125236
    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 mar 7 11:05 .
    drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 mar 5 10:10 ..
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1443962 dic 4 15:04 abi-4.10.0-42-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1501359 feb 16 18:49 abi-4.13.0-36-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 204962 dic 4 15:04 config-4.10.0-42-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 213212 feb 16 18:49 config-4.13.0-36-generic
    drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 mar 7 11:05 grub
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 42833675 mar 5 10:12 initrd.img-4.10.0-42-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 58376815 mar 7 10:59 initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 182704 gen 28 2016 memtest86+.bin
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 184380 gen 28 2016 memtest86+.elf
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 184840 gen 28 2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2860 feb 16 18:49 retpoline-4.13.0-36-generic
    -rw------- 1 root root 3722463 dic 4 15:04 System.map-4.10.0-42-generic
    -rw------- 1 root root 3880918 feb 16 18:49 System.map-4.13.0-36-generic
    -rw------- 1 root root 7587600 dic 4 15:04 vmlinuz-4.10.0-42-generic
    -rw------- 1 root root 7870224 feb 16 18:49 vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
```

dkms status

```
 ~$ dkms status
    bbswitch, 0.8, 4.10.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
    bbswitch, 0.8, 4.13.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
    nvidia-384, 384.111, 4.10.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
    nvidia-384, 384.111, 4.13.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
    virtualbox, 5.1.30, 4.10.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
    virtualbox, 5.1.30, 4.13.0-36-generic, x86_64: installed
```

linux-image

```
~$ ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  82412 dic 11 11:08 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 101208 dic  4 15:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.md5sums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  40162 dic  4 15:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  13727 dic  4 15:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.postrm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11581 dic  4 15:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.preinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11391 dic  4 15:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.10.0-42-generic.prerm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  82856 mar  5 10:09 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 101687 feb 16 18:49 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.md5sums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  40162 feb 16 18:49 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  13727 feb 16 18:49 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.postrm
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11581 feb 16 18:49 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.preinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  11391 feb 16 18:49 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic.prerm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      0 mar 16 14:03 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 415834 apr  6  2017 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic.md5sums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    391 apr  6  2017 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    391 apr  6  2017 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic.postrm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 345004 dic 11 11:08 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 416179 dic  4 15:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic.md5sums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    391 dic  4 15:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    391 dic  4 15:04 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.10.0-42-generic.postrm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 358075 mar  5 10:09 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 431457 feb 16 18:49 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic.md5sums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    391 feb 16 18:49 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic.postinst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    391 feb 16 18:49 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-extra-4.13.0-36-generic.postrm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    162 mar  5 10:09 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-generic.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    159 feb 16 19:46 /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-generic.md5sums
```

Suggested in answer

```
   ~$ dpkg -l "*linux-*" | grep "4.10.0-19" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2
    linux-image-4.10.0-19-generic
    linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade broke the apt database... That is not nice, but it happens. In order to fix this issue, you need to manully remove the broken packages.

First find all packages with that version

```
dpkg -l "*linux-*" | grep "4.10.0-19" | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Then remove the found packages with `dpkg --purge`

```
sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.10.0-19-generic
```

If there are new error messages take a look at `dpkg --force-help`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Your command gives : linux-image-4.10.0-19-generic linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic . And when I m trying to remove them, sudo dpkg --purge  --force-all linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic, same problem : 'Removing linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic (4.10.0-19.21) ... depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.10.0-19-generic: No such file or directory '.  When I am trying to remove the other one,  sudo dpkg --purge --force-all linux-image-4.10.0-19-generic, I have 'dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove linux-image-4.10.0-19-generic which isn't installed'

Comment: FIne, it worked!!! Thx! I had to do: 'sudo rm linux-image-extra-4.10.0-19-generic.postrm' in addition before  'sudo dpkg --purge --force-all linux-image-4.10.0-19-generic' as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/48014/how-force-remove-when-post-installation-script-always-fail